# Problemas subiendo archivos en proyecto Laravel 5.5 en un hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mvc, phpmyadmin

Me encuentro subiendo un proyecto de Laravel 5.5 al hosting gratuito 000webhost. Un usuario puede subir imágenes a un post, cuando lo pruebo en la computadora sin subirlo a un hosting funciona perfectamente. La imagen se sube a la carpeta public/image del proyecto y guarda correctamente la dirección donde se guardo en un campo llamado file, que es un campo de post.

Cuando subo el proyecto al hosting con el file manager guardo la carpeta public del proyecto en public_html y el resto de las carpetas en una carpeta llamada uejil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al subir imágenes en lugar de guardarse en public_html/image se guarda en uejil/public/image.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ademas de esto cuando guarda la direccion, la guarda de esta forma por dar un ejemplo: 
https://ueducativajosefairausquinlopez.000webhostapp.com/image/DKiuYckrZqOmA4gn0uJqpBc5Q2kXBFyVii2RSCsu.jpeg

El nombre de la imagen es correcto pero no la dirección. Debido a esto no se puede visualizar la imagen subida del post.

Agrego el código de filesystems:

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
*/

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
| reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
| will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
|
*/

'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],

];
```

Y el codigo del controlador de post

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;  
use App\Http\Requests\PostStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\PostUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


use App\Post;
use App\Category;
use App\Tag;

class PostController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->paginate();


    return view('admin.posts.index', compact('posts'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->pluck('name', 'id');
    $tags       = Tag::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();

     return view('admin.posts.create', compact('categories', 'tags'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
{
    $post = Post::create($request->all());
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    //IMAGE 
    if($request->file('file')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('file'));
        $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //NOTAS
    if($request->file('file2')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('notas',  $request->file('file2'));
        $post->fill(['file2' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //TAGS
    $post->tags()->attach($request->get('tags'));

    return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)->with('info', 'Entrada creada con éxito');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    return view('admin.posts.show', compact('post'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $post       = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    $categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->pluck('name', 'id');
    $tags       = Tag::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();

    return view('admin.posts.edit', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(PostUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);

    $post->fill($request->all())->save();

    //IMAGE 
    if($request->file('file')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',  $request->file('file'));
        $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //NOTAS
    if($request->file('file2')){
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('notas',  $request->file('file2'));
        $post->fill(['file2' => asset($path)])->save();
    }

    //TAGS
    $post->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));

    return redirect()->route('posts.edit', $post->id)->with('info', 'Entrada actualizada con éxito');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $this->authorize('pass', $post);
    $post->delete();

    return back()->with('info', 'Eliminado correctamente');
}
}
```

Si hace falta agregar otro código, por favor avisar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que registrar la nueva ruta publica dado que ya no es public sino public_html

`\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`

```
    /**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html');
    });
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5